# Difference of Squares: Always More Than One Solution For Odd Composite #s?

Tags: factoring

I've been looking at the pattern in the difference of squares recently. I've seen proofs that for a given prime, there is a unique pair of squares that differ by that prime.

What I'd like to know is: is there guaranteed to be more than one pair of squares with a difference of $m$ where $m$ is an odd, composite integer $> 0$?

The sequence of values $q^2 - p^2$ where $p = q - 1$ will produce a difference of squares of the form $( q - p )( q + p ) = ( 1 )( 2q - 1 ) = m$. There is always a solution for m using this approach, but it's not terribly interesting for factorization purposes. I'd like to find solutions where $p = q - k | k > 1$.

I can perform a search in $O(\sqrt{m})$ to find one/all such solutions - but I'm not sure that there is *always* a solution for $m$ (other than $k = 1$). Are there any existing proofs on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $m^2-n^2 = c$ as $(m+n)(m-n) = c$, for odd composite $c$.  Since $c$ is composite, it can be written as a product of two natural numbers in at least two different ways: $c \times 1$ and $r \times s$, for odd $r > s$ (without loss of generality).  So we can have

$$
m = \frac{c+1}{2}, \quad n = \frac{c-1}{2}
$$

for the former case, and

$$
m = \frac{r+s}{2}, \quad n = \frac{r-s}{2}
$$

for the latter case.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much :) I'll accept as answer once it lets me do that

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams: Strange.  It should always allow you to accept an answer; what it might not let you do is upvote it. :-/

Comment: Says I gotta wait 8 minutes >.>

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams: Ahh, I see.  Well, I'm in no rush. :-)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in the OP I specified that I was looking at odd integers > 0 :)

Comment: Yeah, was looking for that, and found it, eventually, but it would have been easier to find if you had stuck with OPs original letters.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I would have liked to, but OP used $p$ in two different ways: once as the prime difference of squares, and once as the larger of the two numbers being squared.  So I used $m$ and $n$ for the two numbers being squared.  I figured I'd use $c$ for composite as OP used $p$ for prime.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I did do that haha, my bad :)

Comment: Accepted as answer :) Thanks guys